Index not getting applied while $lookup for one of my query but for others it's getting applied. Not able to find out the mistake i am doing
Index not getting applied while $lookup (Customers lookup in my query, _id index is not getting applied) for one of my query but for other query it’s getting applied.
Below is the plan details which is not taking index on customers lookup:
{
"explainVersion": "1",
"stages": [
    {
        "$cursor": {
            "queryPlanner": {
                "namespace": "storedb.Case",
                "indexFilterSet": false,
                "parsedQuery": {
                    "$and": [
                        {
                            "CreatedOn": {
                                "$lte": "2024-03-11T00:00:00.000Z"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "CreatedOn": {
                                "$gte": "2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "queryHash": "DA7A911E",
                "planCacheKey": "10BEEF52",
                "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
                "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
                "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
                "winningPlan": {
                    "stage": "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                    "transformBy": {
                        "_id": true,
                        "IsInternal": true,
                        "CaseNumber": true,
                        "Subject": true,
                        "CaseComments": true
                    },
                    "inputStage": {
                        "stage": "FETCH",
                        "inputStage": {
                            "stage": "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern": {
                                "CreatedOn": -1
                            },
                            "indexName": "CreatedOn_-1",
                            "isMultiKey": false,
                            "multiKeyPaths": {
                                "CreatedOn": []
                            },
                            "isUnique": false,
                            "isSparse": false,
                            "isPartial": false,
                            "indexVersion": 2,
                            "direction": "forward",
                            "indexBounds": {
                                "CreatedOn": [
                                    "[new Date(1710115200000), new Date(1704067200000)]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "rejectedPlans": []
            },
            "executionStats": {
                "executionSuccess": true,
                "nReturned": 1510,
                "executionTimeMillis": 222975,
                "totalKeysExamined": 1510,
                "totalDocsExamined": 1510,
                "executionStages": {
                    "stage": "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
                    "nReturned": 1510,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1,
                    "works": 1511,
                    "advanced": 1510,
                    "needTime": 0,
                    "needYield": 0,
                    "saveState": 5,
                    "restoreState": 5,
                    "isEOF": 1,
                    "transformBy": {
                        "_id": true,
                        "IsInternal": true,
                        "CaseNumber": true,
                        "Subject": true,
                        "CaseComments": true
                    },
                    "inputStage": {
                        "stage": "FETCH",
                        "nReturned": 1510,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1,
                        "works": 1511,
                        "advanced": 1510,
                        "needTime": 0,
                        "needYield": 0,
                        "saveState": 5,
                        "restoreState": 5,
                        "isEOF": 1,
                        "docsExamined": 1510,
                        "alreadyHasObj": 0,
                        "inputStage": {
                            "stage": "IXSCAN",
                            "nReturned": 1510,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1,
                            "works": 1511,
                            "advanced": 1510,
                            "needTime": 0,
                            "needYield": 0,
                            "saveState": 5,
                            "restoreState": 5,
                            "isEOF": 1,
                            "keyPattern": {
                                "CreatedOn": -1
                            },
                            "indexName": "CreatedOn_-1",
                            "isMultiKey": false,
                            "multiKeyPaths": {
                                "CreatedOn": []
                            },
                            "isUnique": false,
                            "isSparse": false,
                            "isPartial": false,
                            "indexVersion": 2,
                            "direction": "forward",
                            "indexBounds": {
                                "CreatedOn": [
                                    "[new Date(1710115200000), new Date(1704067200000)]"
                                ]
                            },
                            "keysExamined": 1510,
                            "seeks": 1,
                            "dupsTested": 0,
                            "dupsDropped": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "allPlansExecution": []
            }
        },
        "nReturned": 1510,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$CaseComments"
        },
        "nReturned": 1891,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 6
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "CreatedById": "$CaseComments.CreatedById",
            "CommentCreatedDate": "$CaseComments.CreatedOn"
        },
        "nReturned": 1891,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 7
    },
    {
        **"$lookup": {
            "from": "Customer",
            "as": "Customers",
            "localField": "CreatedById",
            "foreignField": "_id"
        },
        "totalDocsExamined": 438532718,
        "totalKeysExamined": 0,
        "collectionScans": 3782,
        "indexesUsed": [],
        "nReturned": 1891,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 222956**
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "CommentedBy": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$Customers.Email",
                    {
                        "$const": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "nReturned": 1891,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 222963
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": true,
            "CommentCreatedDate": true,
            "Case Number": "$CaseNumber",
            "Case Subject": "$Subject",
            "CaseComments": {
                "Description": true
            },
            "CommentedBy::multi-filter": "$CommentedBy",
            "Case Type": "$IsInternal"
        },
        "nReturned": 1891,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 222970
    }
],
"serverInfo": {
    "host": "atlas-gj4g2l-shard-00-01.7g9o2.mongodb.net",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "5.0.26",
    "gitVersion": "0b4f1ea980b5380a66425a90b414106a191365f4"
},
"serverParameters": {
    "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": 0,
    "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600
},
"command": {
    "aggregate": "Case",
    "pipeline": [
        {
            "$match": {
                "CreatedOn": {
                    "$gte": "2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "$lte": "2024-03-11T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "CaseNumber": 1,
                "Subject": 1,
                "IsInternal": 1,
                "CaseComments": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": "$CaseComments"
        },
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "CreatedById": "$CaseComments.CreatedById",
                "CommentCreatedDate": "$CaseComments.CreatedOn"
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "Customer",
                "localField": "CreatedById",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "Customers"
            }
        },
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "CommentedBy": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$Customers.Email",
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "Case Number": "$CaseNumber",
                "Case Subject": "$Subject",
                "CaseComments.Description": 1,
                "CommentedBy::multi-filter": "$CommentedBy",
                "CommentCreatedDate": 1,
                "Case Type": "$IsInternal"
            }
        }
    ],
    "cursor": {},
    "maxTimeMS": 60000,
    "$db": "storedb"
},
"ok": 1,
"$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": {
        "$timestamp": "7354702921088368645"
    },
    "signature": {
        "hash": "mJzHl346uQo2bICb2Iw2z5f1xJM=",
        "keyId": {
            "low": 1,
            "high": 1702919047,
            "unsigned": false
        }
    }
},
"operationTime": {
    "$timestamp": "7354702921088368645"
}

}
In other query, it’s using the index (while customer lookup):
{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "Customer",
            "as": "Customers",
            "localField": "SalesRepId",
            "foreignField": "_id"
        },
        "totalDocsExamined": 224,
        "totalKeysExamined": 224,
        "collectionScans": 0,
        **"indexesUsed": [
            "_id_"
        ],**
        "nReturned": 224,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 73
    }

Not able to find out the mistake i am doing. Please let me know if need more details

Is CreatedById null or missing at point? What does a sample document look like if you run the aggregation pipeline up until the $lookup stage?

Does it behave differently if you use localField:"CaseComments.CreatedById"?
